# Garbage cans color coding in the USA

Tags: garbage-disposal

After moving from apartments to a new house, my wife and I found only two garbage cans: a blue one and a green one.

We use the blue one for recyclable things like clean bottles, cartons, and so on.

The green one is filled with non-recyclable garbage.

- Are we using the two cans the right way?
- Do I use a gray can (if I have one) for compostable food waste, grass, etc?
- Who is responsible for providing us with a can for compost?

**P.S.** Sorry, it's actually three questions. If needed, I can post them separately.

Comment: Has the government actually spent our money regulating the colors of trash cans nationwide? I thought the color was what the collection service could get the best deal on. Maybe it might be standardized for a municipality to simplify handling waste from different service providers. Or perhaps there are just a few manufacturers of commercial trash cans and they picked some colors for what they offer. If there are actually national standards, I'm glad my tax money isn't being wasted on needy people and is being used, instead, for the worthy cause of ensuring trash cans are the correct color.

Comment: I have no idea about the nationwide trash cans color regulation vs county or city rules. I mentioned the US in the title so that it's obvious I'm not asking about Sweden, Australia, South Africa, or Brazil :)

Comment: In our area, blue is recycling, green is compostable food and yard waste, and gray is garbage.  You have to contract and pay for a gray one.  @fixer1234 more likely just industry practice, like how USB became how you charge your phone.  If your town/garbage company wants to buy 10,000 recycling bins, ten companies have them in blue, but yellow would be a special order from only two companies at twice the price.

Comment: VTC since this is dependent on which city, county, or even neighborhood you live in. Green is for recyclables where I live, and I've seen red used for recyclables as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is far too localized to be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your city waste department handles color coding of garbage, recyclable materials and other such items.Typically you are correct - Blue for recycle and Green for Garbage.

- Who provides a can for compost - if they provide one at all.
- What can is used for what purpose.

All Cities in the USA have their own requirements.
You will need to look in your City Web Site page and they should have a contact number for the Waste Collection Division - they can and will provide you with the details you request.

Comment: Whomever sends you the pickup bill would be a good place to call, whether it is the city or a contractor.